# gradle multi project build override dependencies in child

Tags: gradle, dependencies, multi-project, gradle-multi-project-build

In a gradle multi project build:

```
root << applies: dependency{ 'org:module:version1' }
|- foo (version1) is ok here
|- bar (version1) not ok here, I need to use version 2
```

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative you can use is the [`strictly`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html) keyword. In your `bar` module you can write something like:

```
dependencies {
    //Other dependencies
    compile("org:module") {
        version {
            strictly version2
        }
        because("Only version2 works in this module")
    }
}
```

Also, if you check your `bar` module dependency graph with:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies
```

You'll get an output like this:

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- project :
|    +--- org.sample:dependency:1.0
|    +--- org.sample:other-dependency:1.0
|    \--- org:module:{strictly version2} -> version2
```